# Can Zeeman effect be observed around black holes?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, quantum-spin, spin-orbit

I'm trying to study the motion of charged-spinning test particles around a black hole immersed in the magnetic field. There will be spin-orbit coupling due to the spin of the particle, and external magnetic field around the black hole. Can we observe the Zeeman effect around black holes?
If we plot the trajectories of charged-spinning particles around black holes and plot the orbits where epicyclic oscillations can be observed, is it possible to examine the Zeeman effect there? If so how to examine it from trajectories?